# Do you know how I can authenticate an app for Facebook in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to to get tokens so something like that so that an app will be able to search a user in Facebook.

I've tried http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk but it is either for authenticating a user or it is not working.

For example this one is for authenticating a user to the app
http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php but I want to authenticate my app to facebook.

This one give error http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/tests/tests.php
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in...

And I do not know my ap's tokens. Also I do not know whether those tokes are used for once or they can be used multiple times.

Comment: Is your Facebook application created using FBML or iframe? As that will affect the solution...

Comment: It is going to be build in PHP. A visitor comes to a web site, enters an email address. the web site returnes either; "this mail adrees is registered at facebook" or "this mail address is not registered at facebook". there is no user authentication. i only want an program that will make a search in facebook for an email adress. however i do not know where to get that token? are they used for once or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the email addresses (or proxy email addresses) of the users that gave your app that permission. There is no way to write a facebook application that accesses email addresses (or most any data) of arbitrary users.

Comment: Downvote without reasoning isn't really helpful. Do you think the answer is wrong, or do you just not like it?